# ValueError: Gas estimation failed

Tags: python, blockchain, brownie

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&t=35244s) course on YouTube and on lesson 10 (Defi and Aave), I am getting this error when trying to borrow;

> ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'The execution failed due to an exception.'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.

I thought it may be because of low funds but I was wrong as I increased the funds and also decreased the amount to borrow (kept it very low).

Here is the code:

```
def main():
    account = get_account()
    erc20_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["weth_token"]

    if network.show_active() in ["mainnet-fork"]:
        get_weth()

    lending_pool = get_lending_pool()
    print(lending_pool)

    # Approve sending out erc20 tokens
    approve_erc20(amount, lending_pool.address, erc20_address, account)

    tx = lending_pool.deposit(
        erc20_address, amount, account.address, 0, {"from": account}
    )
    tx.wait(1)
    print("Deposited!!!")
    borrowable_eth, total_debt = get_borrowable_data(lending_pool, account)
    print("lets borrow!!")

    dai_eth_price_feed = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["dai_eth_price_feed"]
    dai_eth_price = get_asset_price(dai_eth_price_feed)

    amount_dai_to_borrow = (borrowable_eth * 0.05) / dai_eth_price

    print(
        f"Borrowing {amount_dai_to_borrow} DAI ({Web3.toWei(borrowable_eth*0.05, 'ether')} wei)"
    )

    dai_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["dai_token"]

    borrow_tx = lending_pool.borrow(
        dai_address,
        Web3.toWei(amount_dai_to_borrow, "ether"),
        1,
        0,
        account.address,
        {"from": account},
    )

    borrow_tx.wait(1)
    print("we borrowed some DAI")
```

`deposit` works fine but borrow gives this error. Also my brownie-config.yaml is as;

```
dependencies:
  - aave/protocol-v2@1.0.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@aave=aave/protocol-v2@1.0.1'

networks:
  default: mainnet-fork
  kovan:
    weth_token: '0xd0A1E359811322d97991E03f863a0C30C2cF029C'
    lending_pool_addresses_provider: '0x88757f2f99175387ab4c6a4b3067c77a695b0349'
    dai_eth_price_feed: '0x22B58f1EbEDfCA50feF632bD73368b2FdA96D541'
    dai_token: '0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa'
  mainnet-fork:
    weth_token: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2'
    lending_pool_addresses_provider: '0xB53C1a33016B2DC2fF3653530bfF1848a515c8c5'
    dai_eth_price_feed: '0x773616E4d11A78F511299002da57A0a94577F1f4'
    dai_token: '0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F'
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Comment: You need to look at the full exception trace to see where the ValueError is raised. It's certainly not coming from any of the code you've shown

Comment: As you can see that there are print statements before i borrow any DAI and also i am deposting some eth before that, that is working fine. It is the borrow function where the things break

Answer (score 0):

So after some research, i found that it was just the problem with the version of aave i was using (v2). I changed to v3 and everything works fine.